# TemplateDoesNotExist Django Error

Tags: django

I am trying to build a login page form. In my urls.py, I have linked the file to the built in Django login view, and pass in the path to a template directory. I have login folder inside the template and login.html file inside the login folder.

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
'template_name': 'login/login.html'
}),
```

In settings.py, I have provided the directory where my templates are being stored.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates'),
)
```

When I run the runserver command, it shows TemplateDoesNotExist

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:login/login.html
```

Comment: check your permissions on your templates folder (ls -l command or equivalent). Also, check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types

Comment: do you have a templates folder in the root app directory

Comment: Can you add your folder structure here as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same problem, it turns out the template path was incorrect. I needed to use `'../templates'`, instead of `'templates'` in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../templates'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be define your Directories in another settings file, to alleviate the need to use ugly relative path in your template dirs:

```
// _paths.py
SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

// _templates.py
from settings/_paths.py import SETTINGS_DIR

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Adjust accordingly based on your folder structure.